# iphone application unit testing problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing, xcode, ipad

If followed the [apple tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html) for setting up application unit tests.

I have two issues with "Application Unit Tests".

The first is that I get a warning running application unit tests (see below).

warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.2.2/Symbols/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsBundleInjection.framework/DevToolsBundleInjection" (file not found).

The second is that after running application unit tests, when I switch back to my application target, it seems to run the unit test build until I do a full clean. That is, the application doesn't run, but instead the application unit test suite runs.

My guess is because the application unit test target executable is the same as the application target executable (per the instructions) and when I switch to build and rub application it doesn't rebuild the executable for some reason.

I have confirmed the behavior occurs in the iPhoneUnitTests sample application. So, my work around is to do a "clean all targets" when switching back to running the application rather than running the application tests.

My XCode version info is:

Developer Information:

Version:  3.2 (10M2262)
  Location: /Developer
  Applications:
  Xcode:    3.2.3 (1688)
  Interface Builder:    3.2.3 (788)
  Instruments:  2.7 (2529)
  Dashcode: 3.0.1 (330)
  SDKs:
  Mac OS X:
  10.5: (9L31a)
  10.6: (10M2262)
  iPhone OS:
  3.2:  (7B500)
  4.0:  (8A400a)
  iPhone Simulator:
  3.2:  (7W367a)
  4.0:  (8A400a)

My questions are: 1) have other people observed this behavior? and 2) Is there a solution which allows switching back to running the application without requiring a "clean all targets" and 3) what is the meaning of the warning and should I be worried about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also struggled with the set up of my application tests. After I read your post I found another description; which has one thing different. The purpose is to set the application target name different from the original application name. Here's the [website](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/12/sample-iphone-application-with-complete.html).
The say:

> for all Configurations set the
>   "Build→Packaging→Product Name" to
>   something distinct from the original
>   target

This solved my problem that the debugger didn't stop at the set breakpoints. I think this also solves your problem when switching from the tests back to the app.

Best
Wolfgang

Answer (score 1):

iPhone Unit Testing is very fragile, if you're just starting I would recommend a switch to [GHUnit](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit/archives/master)

[Here's a great tutorial on how to get it all working](http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/iPhone.SettingUpTheEnvionment)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll check check it out.